# Rxjs 6 - Fetch an array and push object to array for each result

Tags: arrays, loops, rxjs, fetch, subscribe

Im a beginner with Rxjs, and I didn't find a topic which really answer to my question.

Basically, I want to have an Observable which return an array of Pokemons with their informations.
For this, I need first of all to do a request in order to fetch an array of the Pokemons's names. Then, I want to loop in this array to get the all the informations about a pokemon, put it in an array and return this array.

If I understood well, I need to use the concatMap operator for that, so I did this :

```
getPokemons(): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
const url = `${this.pokemonsUrl}pokemon/?limit=5`;

return this.http
  .get<Pokemon[]>(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(pokemons => {
      const listpokemons = pokemons.results.map(pokemon => {
        return this.getPokemon(pokemon.name);
      });
      return listpokemons;
    }),
    tap(_ => this.log(`Fetched Pokemons !`)),
    catchError(this.handleError(`getPokemons`, []))
  );
}

getPokemon(name: string): Observable<Pokemon> {
 const url = `${this.pokemonsUrl}pokemon/${name}`;

 return this.http.get<Pokemon>(url).pipe (
  tap(_ => this.log(`Fetched Pokemon name=${name} !`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<Pokemon>(`getPokemon name=${name}`))
 );
}
```

With this code, when I subscribe to my Observable, Im fetching the observable object of getPokemon and not the answer of the Observable, and not in an array (because if I try to push the result of getPokemon in an array, I have an error).

This is what I currently return:

[console.log of datas returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZOn.png)

And this is what i'd like :

```
[PokemonObject, PokemonObject, PokemonObject, ...]
```

If anyone could explain to me how to do this it would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ur code what return from `concatMap` is an array of observable, because i guess `pokemons.results` is an array and array.map returns an array. `concatMap` can't process array it only runs `Observable<any>`, you can try `concat` or `forkJoin` if sequence is not a concern instead

```
return this.http
  .get<Pokemon[]>(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(pokemons => {
      const listpokemons = pokemons.results.map(pokemon => {
        return this.getPokemon(pokemon.name);
      });
      return concat(listpokemons);
    }),
    tap(_ => this.log(`Fetched Pokemons !`)),
    catchError(this.handleError(`getPokemons`, []))
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Fan ! The solution was indeed forkJoin(). I returned listpokemons like this : return forkJoin(listpokemons);